# Update decimal value to mysql with wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

id, client, year, month, value, days
where value is a decimal(20,2).
In php I insert one line like this:

```
`INSERT INTO table 
(client, year, month, value, days) 
VALUES 
('999999','2015','04','123.45','6')
```

`
And everithing works fine

When I update that register with:

`UPDATE table SET value='444.44' && dias='6' WHERE client='999999' && year='2015' && month='04'`

The value in mysql will be 1.00, but it should be 444.44.

If I delete the record and insert again

`INSERT INTO table (client, year, month, value, days) VALUES ('999999','2015','04','444.44','6')`

It will work fine and value will be 444.44.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The update statement is wrong and should be as

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
value='444.44',
dias='6' 
WHERE client='999999' and year='2015' and month='04'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement is wrong. It should be like this:

```
UPDATE table SET value='444.44', days='6' WHERE client='999999' AND year='2015' AND month='04';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
`UPDATE table SET value='444.44', dias='6' WHERE client='999999' and year='2015' and month='04'`
```